# Background gradient not loading on Safari & Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, gradient, linear-gradients

Trying to make a background gradient to work on Safari and Firefox. On Chrome it works perfect:

```
.gq_s_background_gradient:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(360deg,rgba(43,135,218,0.3) 0%,#161616 85%);
    animation-duration: 2500ms;
    animation-delay: 700ms;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: et_pb_fade;
    animation-name: et_pb_fade;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both !important;
    animation-fill-mode: both !important;}
```

Comment: Please provide a working demo/snippet reproducing your problem. Without HTML, no way to know if `opacity: 0` or null dimensions of the pseudo has something to do with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you use `opacity:0` ?
and

set the background for all browser:

```
background-image:

-webkit-linear-gradient(360deg,rgba(43,135,218,0.3) 0%,#161616 85%);

background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(360deg,rgba(43,135,218,0.3) 0%,#161616 85%);  

background-image:-o-linear-gradient(360deg,rgba(43,135,218,0.3) 0%,#161616 85%);

background-image:   linear-gradient(360deg,rgba(43,135,218,0.3) 0%,#161616 85%);
```

Comment: Don't suggest those silly prefixes on everything. There never even was a `-ms-` prefix for linear-gradient.

Comment: thanks for mention!! its  typing mistake no need to vote minus!

Comment: Used this and removed the animation part, working now. Tnx

Comment: @MAR we no more need any prefix for gradient, you can remove all of them

Comment: Prefixes? [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient) and/or [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) (and browserslist).Here nope